# Java class implementing first-in-first-out queue

Tags: java, class, queue

I have an upcoming exam and am struggling with this question, was hoping someone could help please.

Provide a complete Java class that implements the interface

```
interface StringQueue 
{ boolean isEmpty(); 
void add(String c); 
String front(); 
void removeFront(); 
}
```

The class should provide an implementation of a standard first-in-first-out queue. The characters in the queue should be stored in a singly-linked list constructed using of objects of type QueueCell; you must write this class as an inner class. (You must not use the LinkedList class from the Collections Framework). The front and removeFront methods should throw an exception of type QueueException when applied to an empty queue; you may assume that the QueueException class has already been written.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is your question? This is just a list of requirements

Comment: I don't think it will help you to see an implementation.  Certainly, it won't help you to *learn* an implementation.  It is highly unlikely that the upcoming exam will ask you to implement a stack ... if a past exam did.

Comment: So what is your problem here? By just googling you can find examples of how FIFO works. Is it so hard to write 2 methods, first returning first element and removing it, and second method which puts new elements at the end of list?

Comment: how you wanna add String while it's of Type QueueCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to have a look at my implementation and try to write your own. Otherwise, if you just copy and paste it, it'll be of no use to you.

**Interface**:

```
public interface StringQueue {
    boolean isEmpty();
    void add(String c);
    String front();
    void removeFront();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class StringQueueImpl implements StringQueue {
    private QueueCell head;
    private int size = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String c) {
        if(head == null){
            head = new QueueCell(c);
        } else {
            QueueCell current = head;
            while(current != null){
                if(current.next == null){
                    current.next = new QueueCell(c);
                    break;
                } else {
                    current = head.next;
                }
            }
        }
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public String front() throws QueueException {
        if(size == 0 || head == null){
            throw new QueueException();
        }
        return head.value;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeFront() throws QueueException {
        if(size == 0 || head == null){
            throw new QueueException();
        }

        if(head.next != null){
            head = head.next;
        } else { // if only 1 element is in the queue
            head = null;
        }
        size--;
    }

    private static class QueueCell {
        private QueueCell next;
        private String value;

        QueueCell(String s){
            value = s;
        }
    }

    public static class QueueException extends RuntimeException {
        public QueueException(){
            super("Queue is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you implement isEmpty ?

Comment: @John just a `boolean` method with `return size == 0` or `return head == null`, either one is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy try

Implementation :

```
 private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
 public void add(E item) {
    list.addLast(item);
 }
 public E removeFront() {
    return list.poll();
 }
 public boolean isEmpty() {
    return !list.isEmpty();
 }
 public int size() {
    return list.size();
 }
 public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {
    while (q.hasItems()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
 }
```

Comment: What part of `You must not use the LinkedList class from the Collections Framework` did you not understand?